# Variadic Zip Function in Swift

Tags: swift, iterator, tuples, sequence, variadic-functions

## Variadic Zip Function

#### Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.4

I have been using Apple's native `zip(_:_:)` recently and I ran into a situation whereby I needed to`zip` more than two sequences.

So I looked for and found the declaration of [`zip(_:_:)` on Swift's GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Zip.swift) page. I took that information and was able to overload `zip(_:_:)` to accept four parameters, `zip(_:_:_:_:)`. I am aware that I can painstakingly overload `zip` to support whatever number of arguments I chose one at a time, but this is inflexible, time consuming, and I feel that a variadic option would be a much better choice.

#### Question:

***How to make the native `zip` function accept a variadic parameter that can hold any number of sequence inputs.***

---

### Apple's Native `zip(_:_:)` Function

```swift
/// Creates a sequence of pairs built out of two underlying sequences.
///
/// In the `Zip2Sequence` instance returned by this function, the elements of
/// the *i*th pair are the *i*th elements of each underlying sequence. The
/// following example uses the `zip(_:_:)` function to iterate over an array
/// of strings and a countable range at the same time:
///
///     let words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
///     let numbers = 1...4
///
///     for (word, number) in zip(words, numbers) {
///         print("\(word): \(number)")
///     }
///     // Prints "one: 1"
///     // Prints "two: 2
///     // Prints "three: 3"
///     // Prints "four: 4"
///
/// If the two sequences passed to `zip(_:_:)` are different lengths, the
/// resulting sequence is the same length as the shorter sequence. In this
/// example, the resulting array is the same length as `words`:
///
///     let naturalNumbers = 1...Int.max
///     let zipped = Array(zip(words, naturalNumbers))
///     // zipped == [("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("three", 3), ("four", 4)]
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - sequence1: The first sequence or collection to zip.
///   - sequence2: The second sequence or collection to zip.
/// - Returns: A sequence of tuple pairs, where the elements of each pair are
///   corresponding elements of `sequence1` and `sequence2`.
@inlinable // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
public func zip<Sequence1, Sequence2>(
    _ sequence1: Sequence1, _ sequence2: Sequence2
    ) -> Zip2Sequence<Sequence1, Sequence2> {
    return Zip2Sequence(_sequence1: sequence1, _sequence2: sequence2)
}

/// A sequence of pairs built out of two underlying sequences.
///
/// In a `Zip2Sequence` instance, the elements of the *i*th pair are the *i*th
/// elements of each underlying sequence. To create a `Zip2Sequence` instance,
/// use the `zip(_:_:)` function.
///
/// The following example uses the `zip(_:_:)` function to iterate over an
/// array of strings and a countable range at the same time:
///
///     let words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
///     let numbers = 1...4
///
///     for (word, number) in zip(words, numbers) {
///         print("\(word): \(number)")
///     }
///     // Prints "one: 1"
///     // Prints "two: 2
///     // Prints "three: 3"
///     // Prints "four: 4"
@_fixed_layout // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
public struct Zip2Sequence<Sequence1 : Sequence, Sequence2 : Sequence> {
    @usableFromInline // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
    internal let _sequence1: Sequence1
    @usableFromInline // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
    internal let _sequence2: Sequence2

    @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "Sequence1.Iterator")
    public typealias Stream1 = Sequence1.Iterator
    @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "Sequence2.Iterator")
    public typealias Stream2 = Sequence2.Iterator

    /// Creates an instance that makes pairs of elements from `sequence1` and
    /// `sequence2`.
    @inlinable // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
    public // @testable
    init(_sequence1 sequence1: Sequence1, _sequence2 sequence2: Sequence2) {
        (_sequence1, _sequence2) = (sequence1, sequence2)
    }
}

extension Zip2Sequence {
    /// An iterator for `Zip2Sequence`.
    @_fixed_layout // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
    public struct Iterator {
        @usableFromInline // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
        internal var _baseStream1: Sequence1.Iterator
        @usableFromInline // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
        internal var _baseStream2: Sequence2.Iterator
        @usableFromInline // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
        internal var _reachedEnd: Bool = false

        /// Creates an instance around a pair of underlying iterators.
        @inlinable // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
        internal init(
            _ iterator1: Sequence1.Iterator,
            _ iterator2: Sequence2.Iterator
            ) {
            (_baseStream1, _baseStream2) = (iterator1, iterator2)
        }
    }
}

extension Zip2Sequence.Iterator: IteratorProtocol {
    /// The type of element returned by `next()`.
    public typealias Element = (Sequence1.Element, Sequence2.Element)

    /// Advances to the next element and returns it, or `nil` if no next element
    /// exists.
    ///
    /// Once `nil` has been returned, all subsequent calls return `nil`.
    @inlinable // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
    public mutating func next() -> Element? {
        // The next() function needs to track if it has reached the end.  If we
        // didn't, and the first sequence is longer than the second, then when we
        // have already exhausted the second sequence, on every subsequent call to
        // next() we would consume and discard one additional element from the
        // first sequence, even though next() had already returned nil.
        if _reachedEnd {
            return nil
        }

        guard let element1 = _baseStream1.next(),
            let element2 = _baseStream2.next() else {
                _reachedEnd = true
                return nil
        }

        return (element1, element2)
    }
}

extension Zip2Sequence: Sequence {
    public typealias Element = (Sequence1.Element, Sequence2.Element)

    /// Returns an iterator over the elements of this sequence.
    @inlinable // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
    public func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        return Iterator(
            _sequence1.makeIterator(),
            _sequence2.makeIterator())
    }
}

// @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "Zip2Sequence.Iterator")
public typealias Zip2Iterator<T, U> = Zip2Sequence<T, U>.Iterator where T: Sequence, U: Sequence
```

---

### `zip(_:_:_:_:)` Function Overload (my implementation)

```swift
/// Creates a sequence of pairs built out of four underlying sequences.
///
/// In the `Zip4Sequence` instance returned by this function, the elements of
/// the *i*th pair are the *i*th elements of each underlying sequence. The
/// following example uses the `zip(_:_:_:_:)` function to iterate over an array
/// of strings, an array of bolean values, an array of integer values, and a countable range, at the same time:
///
///     let evens = [false, true, false, true)
///     let squares = [1, 4, 9, 16]
///     let words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
///     let numbers = 1...4
///
///     for (word, number, even, square) in zip(words, numbers, evens, squares) {
///         print("\(word): \(number) --> \(number) is \(even ? "even" : "odd") and \(number)² = \(square)")
///     }
///     // Prints "one: 1 --> 1 is odd and 1² = 1"
///     // Prints "two: 2 --> 2 is even and 2² = 4"
///     // Prints "three: 3 --> 3 is odd and 3² = 9"
///     // Prints "four: 4 --> 4 is even and 4² = 16"
///
/// If the four sequences passed to `zip(_:_:_:_:)` are different lengths, the
/// resulting sequence is the same length as the shorter sequence. In this
/// example, the resulting array is the same length as `words`, `evens`, `and `squares`:
///
///     let naturalNumbers = 1...Int.max
///     let zipped = Array(zip(words, naturalNumbers, evens, squares))
///     // zipped == [("one", 1, false, 1), ("two", 2, true, 4), ("three", 3, false, 9), ("four", 4, true, 16)]
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - sequence1: The first sequence or collection to zip.
///   - sequence2: The second sequence or collection to zip.
///   - sequence3: The third sequence or collection to zip.
///   - sequence4: The fourth sequence or collection to zip.
/// - Returns: A sequence of tuple pairs, where the elements of each pair are
///   corresponding elements of `sequence1`, `sequence2`, `sequence3`, and `sequence3`.
public func zip<Sequence1, Sequence2, Sequence3, Sequence4>(
    _ sequence1: Sequence1, _ sequence2: Sequence2, _ sequence3: Sequence3, _ sequence4: Sequence4
    ) -> Zip4Sequence<Sequence1, Sequence2, Sequence3, Sequence4> {
    return Zip4Sequence(_sequence1: sequence1, _sequence2: sequence2, _sequence3: sequence3, _sequence4: sequence4)
}

/// A sequence of pairs built out of four underlying sequences.
///
/// In a `Zip4Sequence` instance, the elements of the *i*th pair are the *i*th
/// elements of each underlying sequence. To create a `Zip4Sequence` instance,
/// use the `zip(_:_:_:_:)` function.
///
/// The following example uses the `zip(_:_:_:_:)` function to iterate over an array
/// of strings, an array of bolean values, an array of integer values, and a countable range, at the same time:
////
///     let evens = [false, true, false, true)
///     let squares = [1, 4, 9, 16]
///     let words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
///     let numbers = 1...4
///
///     for (word, number, even, square) in zip(words, numbers, evens, squares) {
///         print("\(word): \(number) --> \(number) is \(even ? "even" : "odd") and \(number)² = \(square)")
///     }
///     // Prints "one: 1 --> 1 is odd and 1² = 1"
///     // Prints "two: 2 --> 2 is even and 2² = 4"
///     // Prints "three: 3 --> 3 is odd and 3² = 9"
///     // Prints "four: 4 --> 4 is even and 4² = 16"
@_fixed_layout // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
public struct Zip4Sequence<Sequence1 : Sequence, Sequence2 : Sequence, Sequence3 : Sequence, Sequence4 : Sequence> {
    internal let _sequence1: Sequence1
    internal let _sequence2: Sequence2
    internal let _sequence3: Sequence3
    internal let _sequence4: Sequence4

    @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "Sequence1.Iterator")
    public typealias Stream1 = Sequence1.Iterator
    @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "Sequence2.Iterator")
    public typealias Stream2 = Sequence2.Iterator
    @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "Sequence3.Iterator")
    public typealias Stream3 = Sequence3.Iterator
    @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "Sequence4.Iterator")
    public typealias Stream4 = Sequence4.Iterator

    /// Creates an instance that makes pairs of elements from `sequence1` and
    /// `sequence2`.
    public // @testable
    init(_sequence1 sequence1: Sequence1, _sequence2 sequence2: Sequence2, _sequence3 sequence3: Sequence3, _sequence4 sequence4: Sequence4) {
        (_sequence1, _sequence2, _sequence3, _sequence4) = (sequence1, sequence2, sequence3, sequence4)
    }
}

extension Zip4Sequence {
    /// An iterator for `Zip4Sequence`.
    @_fixed_layout // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
    public struct Iterator {
        internal var _baseStream1: Sequence1.Iterator
        internal var _baseStream2: Sequence2.Iterator
        internal var _baseStream3: Sequence3.Iterator
        internal var _baseStream4: Sequence4.Iterator
        internal var _reachedEnd: Bool = false

        /// Creates an instance around a set of 4 underlying iterators.
        internal init(
            _ iterator1: Sequence1.Iterator,
            _ iterator2: Sequence2.Iterator,
            _ iterator3: Sequence3.Iterator,
            _ iterator4: Sequence4.Iterator
            ) {
            (_baseStream1, _baseStream2, _baseStream3, _baseStream4) = (iterator1, iterator2, iterator3, iterator4)
        }
    }
}

extension Zip4Sequence.Iterator: IteratorProtocol {
    /// The type of element returned by `next()`.
    public typealias Element = (Sequence1.Element, Sequence2.Element, Sequence3.Element, Sequence4.Element)

    /// Advances to the next element and returns it, or `nil` if no next element
    /// exists.
    ///
    /// Once `nil` has been returned, all subsequent calls return `nil`.
    public mutating func next() -> Element? {
        // The next() function needs to track if it has reached the end. If we
        // didn't, and the first sequence is longer than the second, third, and
        // fourth, then when we have already exhausted the second, third, and
        // fourth sequence, on every subsequent call to next() we would consume
        // and discard one additional element from the first sequence, even
        // though next() had already returned nil.
        if _reachedEnd {
            return nil
        }

        guard let element1 = _baseStream1.next(),
            let element2 = _baseStream2.next(),
            let element3 = _baseStream3.next(),
            let element4 = _baseStream4.next()
            else {
                _reachedEnd = true
                return nil
        }

        return (element1, element2, element3, element4)
    }
}

extension Zip4Sequence: Sequence {
    public typealias Element = (Sequence1.Element, Sequence2.Element, Sequence3.Element, Sequence4.Element)

    /// Returns an iterator over the elements of this sequence.
    public func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        return Iterator(
            _sequence1.makeIterator(),
            _sequence2.makeIterator(),
            _sequence3.makeIterator(),
            _sequence4.makeIterator())
    }
}

@available(*, deprecated, renamed: "Zip4Sequence.Iterator")
public typealias Zip4Iterator<T, U, V, W> = Zip4Sequence<T, U, V, W>.Iterator where T: Sequence, U: Sequence, V: Sequence, W: Sequence
```

**Caveat:** *This overload only is for a fixed number of inputs whereas I am ideally looking for an `zip` function that accepts an indiscriminate number of `AnySequence` inputs.*

---

Just to reiterate, I am looking to create a **`zip(_: AnySequence...)`** function that I can use to *zip any number of sequences* through the use of a *variadic* parameter.

Thank you everyone in advance for all of your help, I really appreciate it!

---

Comment: One problem is that Swift has no [“Variadic generics”](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#variadic-generics) at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is not completely possible in Swift since we can't have different Array types for Variadic parameters. A possible work around would be to convert all arrays to type `[Any]`, and then zip them all together which forms an array array, and than using `map`, converting the arrays to the wanted tuple using force casting. The solution might be bit dirty but not all too complicated.

```swift
extension Sequence {

    //easy conversion of any sequence to [Any]
    var untyped:[Any] {
        return self as! [Any]
   }
}

func zip(_ untypedSequences:[Any]...) -> [[Any]] {
    let count = untypedSequences.map{$0.count}.min() ?? 0
    return (0..<count).map{ index in untypedSequences.map{ $0[index] } }
}

//Test
let test1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
let test2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let test3 = [7.2, 12.23, 1.3]

let zippedTests = zip(test1.untyped, test2.untyped, test3.untyped).map {
    ($0[0] as! String, $0[1] as! Int, $0[2] as! Double)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need all the functions but you don't need multiple ZipSequence types.

```swift
@inlinable public func zip<Sequence0: Sequence, Sequence1: Sequence, Sequence2: Sequence>(
  _ sequence0: Sequence0, _ sequence1: Sequence1, _ sequence2: Sequence2
) -> AnySequence<(Sequence0.Element, Sequence1.Element, Sequence2.Element)> {
  .init(
    sequence(
      state: (
        sequence0.makeIterator(), sequence1.makeIterator(), sequence2.makeIterator()
      )
    ) {
      .init(
        ($0.0.next(), $0.1.next(), $0.2.next())
      )
    }
  )
}

@inlinable public func zip<
  Sequence0: Sequence, Sequence1: Sequence, Sequence2: Sequence, Sequence3: Sequence
>(
  _ sequence0: Sequence0, _ sequence1: Sequence1, _ sequence2: Sequence2, _ sequence3: Sequence3
) -> AnySequence<(Sequence0.Element, Sequence1.Element, Sequence2.Element, Sequence3.Element)> {
  .init(
    sequence(
      state: (
        sequence0.makeIterator(), sequence1.makeIterator(), sequence2.makeIterator(), sequence3.makeIterator()
      )
    ) {
      .init(
        ($0.0.next(), $0.1.next(), $0.2.next(), $0.3.next())
      )
    }
  )
}
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Exchange three optionals for a single optional tuple.
  /// - Returns: `nil` if any tuple element is `nil`.
  init<Wrapped0, Wrapped1, Wrapped2>(_ optionals: (Wrapped0?, Wrapped1?, Wrapped2?))
  where Wrapped == (Wrapped0, Wrapped1, Wrapped2) {
    switch optionals {
    case let (wrapped0?, wrapped1?, wrapped2?):
      self = (wrapped0, wrapped1, wrapped2)
    default:
      self = nil
    }
  }

  /// Exchange four optionals for a single optional tuple.
  /// - Returns: `nil` if any tuple element is `nil`.
  init<Wrapped0, Wrapped1, Wrapped2, Wrapped3>(_ optionals: (Wrapped0?, Wrapped1?, Wrapped2?, Wrapped3?))
  where Wrapped == (Wrapped0, Wrapped1, Wrapped2, Wrapped3) {
    switch optionals {
    case let (wrapped0?, wrapped1?, wrapped2?, wrapped3?):
      self = (wrapped0, wrapped1, wrapped2, wrapped3)
    default:
      self = nil
    }
  }
}
```